# Typo 3 neos thumbnails

Tags: image, thumbnails, neoscms

I have a media gallery in typo3 neos on frontend. And I get big image with code

```
<a class="js-gallery" href="{f:uri.resource(resource: image.resource)}">
<media:image image="{image}" alt="{alternativeText}" title="{title}" maximumWidth="{maximumWidth}" maximumHeight="{maximumHeight}" />
```

I need to get image thumbnails from big image.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the `maximumWidth` and `maximumHeight` view helper arguments to scale down the image:

```
<media:image image="{image}" alt="{alternativeText}" title="{title}" maximumWidth="400" maximumHeight="300" allowCropping="TRUE" />
```

The `allowCropping` argument will crop the image to fit the given dimensions.